# Page not Found error when Views block containing node titles links placed on a specific content type

Tags: views, theming, javascript, navigation

I have a content type News whose nodes are used to generate two blocks using views "Most read news articles" and "Latest news articles". These blocks are printed through `node--news.tpl.php` tpl file when news is displayed in full view mode.

Problem is that that all the title links in blocks lead to "Page not found" due to URLs overridden as http://example.com/news/node/49610 while actually they should be like http://example.com/node/49610

When checking through firebug I can see that links are correct:

`<span class="views-field views-field-title">
<span class="field-content">
<a class="_link-span-tooltip" href="node/49610">Popular product taken down</a>
</span>
</span>`

All links work perfectly When same blocks are placed on the `<front>`.

Any help to resolve this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That link isn't correct. It should be relative to your web root ("/node/49610") and not the current page ("node/49610").